# Hovering over a userControl

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it so that if I hover my mouse over a user control, it changes its back color, I already did this, but the problem is, it works only if I put the mouse directly on the user control, for instance, if I were to hover over a control without the userControl, it won't change its Back color.

[Picture of a hovered on user control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEG3F.png)

[Picture of a hovered on child of the user control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THr6V.png)

So how can I make it so that even if I hover over the user controls children, it keeps changing its back color?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Style the _container_ instead of the individual "parts" - if it doesn't have a container, create it.

Comment: You mean something like a panel?

Comment: Probably ListItem will be good candidate for styling (depending on technology you've used - it may be called other way)

Comment: Subscribe to the child’s mouse events